# Setting AdvancedPrintingOptions from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I'm working with my friend to create a simple Photo Booth device. We are using DNP RX1 Printer, and this printer has the ability to cut photos in half.
When printing photos directly from windows cutting can be set as Enabled/Disabled via "Advanced Options" window in Printer Properties.

[How to Enable/Disable Cut (2inch cut)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19VqT.png)

I'm working on application for this Photo Booth device (Developed on Windows 7). I'm using C++ and Qt as my GUI framework. There is a QPrintSupport module in Qt library that can be used to print images from my application, and I know how to do it. But the problem is that there is no way to Enable/Disable this "cut photos in half" option using Qt library. It is possible to display settings window to user using QPrintDialog class, but I want the process of taking photo and printing to be automatic ( User only press start button, smiles and waits till photo comes out). My workaround for this problem was to save files to two folders, and use different program to print photos from the first folder with cut option enabled and from the other folder with cut option disabled. But the problem was that printer was sometimes detected as DS-RX1 and sometimes as "DS-RX1 (Copy)" or even "DS-RX1 Copy 1", then this solution didn't work and someone had to manually delete printer from the system and reconnect it.

My question is: Is there a way to print a photo from C++ program using default printer and change this Advanced Printer Option (2inch cut) from C++ code? OR: Is there a way to force this printer to be detected always as DS-RX1?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set priner by substring "DS-RX1".
You can ***get list of available printers*** http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinterinfo.html#availablePrinters by substring and as a variant you can set printer by ***setPrinterName*** function http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setPrinterName